# A question about topology in the palne with rational numbers

Tags: general-topology

Let $G$ be an open set in $R^{2}$ (the whole plane),$F$ be a closed set in $R^{2}$. Is it possible that$G-Q^{2}=F-Q^{2}$ in nontivial situations ? ($Q^{2}$ is the set of all rational points and $G-Q^{2}=F-Q^{2}$ can't be empty or $R^{2}-Q^{2}$.

Comment: There is a potentially interesting question here but in its current form it lacks clarity and you also have to explain your own thoughts about the problem: what did you try to solve it, did you consider the case of rationals in the real line, etc...

Comment: $\overline{G - \Bbb Q^2} = \overline G. \overline{F - \Bbb Q^2} = \overline F = F$. So $F = \overline G$. Since $G - \Bbb Q^2 = \overline G - \Bbb Q^2$. it would require that every boundary point of $G$ has rationals for both coordinates.